# Overriding Meta Character Encoding Declarations

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding, meta-tags, meta

I know that declaring the charset of a page using the older style, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

will override any declarations of the charset of a page using the newer style, like so:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

but I am wondering what will two of the older-style declarations do? Is the first one taken over the second? Is the second taken over the first? Or are they both omitted and simply excluded from the remainder of the algorithm that determines the actual encoding of the page.

**Example**

As an example, I am wondering which character encoding declaration in the below snippet will be accepted and factored into the algorithm that determines the page's character encoding:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    ...
</head>
```

I was unable to find the answer to this in the specs or any other reputable source of documentation (though I could have missed it).

**Side-Note**

I am not asking this question because of a difficulty with properly setting a page's character encoding, but rather because I am curious about the answer and whether or not browsers prefer the first or second declaration. As such, alternative solutions/workarounds will not be viable answers for this question.

Thanks for your help! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a browser is using `meta` tags to determine the character encoding, then the first one of such tags takes effect. This has not been specified in current HTML specifications, but it is the common practice and being standardized in HTML5, see HTML5 CR, clause 8.2.2.2 [Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding).

There is no difference between the two types of `meta` tags mentioned in the question. They are just syntactic variants. It is the order of appearance that matters: the first one is used. (It is relatively simple to test this, but you need to use a page that does not have HTTP header specifying the encoding and does not contain Byte Order Mark, since such information would override *any* `meta` tags.)

Comment: One of the things mentioned on the MDN docs for the `<meta charset...>` tag is the following: *Especially, the HTTP Content-Type header and any BOM elements have precedence over [the `meta charset` element.* When you say that it is being standardized in HTML5, do you mean to say that while the two are semantically similar and while one currently has precedence over the other, in the future this will not be the case?

Comment: Or do you mean to say that the `HTTP Content-Type Header` and the `meta http-equiv="Content-Type"` elements are actually different and have different levels of importance?

Comment: What is being standardized is the treatment of `meta` tags. HTTP headers have precedence over them even according to existing HTML specifications. The priority of BOM over even HTTP headers is current practice, violates the HTTP protocol, and is being standardized in HTML5.